# How to write a readable contact to an NFC tag

Tags: contacts, nfc

I just recently got some NFC tags, and while I was playing around with https://nfc.software's iOS app, I tried to write a contact (by importing a contact) to an NFC tag and then read it, but it was not working. I tested out mail, sms, and a social link, and that worked. Is reading/writing contacts not supported?

Thanks!

PS: Not necessarily related to the app itself, because other apps that I tested would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the built-in tag parser in iOS (for example when scanning in the background) - embedded contacts are not supported.

You can however make this work by storing your vCard on a URL, and then having the URL stored on the tag.

Comment: I suppose that will work. Thanks!